# On what sub-interval of $[0,1]$ does $f_n(x)=x^{1/n}$ converges uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Consider $f_n(x)=x^{1/n}$  on the interval $[0,1]$ . 
I know that $f_n$ converges pointwisely to the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$ and $f(x)=1$ when $0<x \le 1.$

I am wondering whether there is a sub-interval of $[0,1]$ on which $f_n$ converges uniformly the constant function **1**.

Comment: Any interval of the form $(a,b)$ (or $[a,b]$, etc.) where $0 < a \leq b \leq 1$.

Comment: Any $[a,1]$ with $a>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $n\geq 1$, $\lvert f_n-1\rvert = 1-f_n$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ *(check it by differentiation)*, so for any fixed $[a,1]$ with $a>0$ its maximum is attained at $f_n(a)$. It follows that, for any fixed $a\in(0,1]$,
$$
\sup_{x\in[a,1]} \lvert f_n(x)-1\rvert = f_n(a) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0
$$
the limit coming from pointwise convergence at $a$.

As you do not have uniform convergence on $[0,b]$ for any $b>0$ *(as otherwise, the pointwise limit of the sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_n$ would have to be continuous on $[0,b]$, and it is not)*, this is the best you can hope for.

Comment: Thanks! But it seems that this is not what I am asking. I think on any interval $[a,1]$ where $a>0$, $f_n$ converges to the constant function $1$.

Comment: @Hirona Yes, and this is what the answer is proving. Uniform convergence to $1$ on any $[a,1]$ where $a>0$ is fixed; and not uniform convergence on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome!